# Incorrect argument label in call?

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

Help me, please!!! I've only recently started programming in Swift. This is my first project. I get the errormessage: "Incorrect argument label in call". This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("psl",ofType: "mp3"){
        var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)

    }else {
        print("the filepath is empty")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func playSoundSlow(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer.play()
```

I'm not sure what went wrong here is another picture of my code so you can also see the errormessage.[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iTX1.png)

I'm trying to get it to play a mp3 called psl.mp3.
Please, help me!!! I just started and don't know what to do.

P.S. Not a native Englishspeaker, so sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 2 adds new error handling, meaning you don't even have to pass in an error parameter:

```
audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl)
```

This initializer `throws`, meaning if there is an error, you can catch it in a `do-catch` statement. However, since you passed `nil` for the error parameter, I'm assuming you are sure the player is there. That's why I used `try!` without a `do-catch` instead of `try` in a `do-catch`.

Read about the new error handling [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

Comment: @MerithV Since it worked, can you accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path))
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()            

    } catch {
        print("Catch error in playUsingAudioPlayer")
   }
```